# Having trouble installing modules for node.js with kiwi

Tags: node.js

I am having trouble with kiwi, the package loader from node.js

I have installed kiwi and have the following feedback from the terminal:

```
bingomanatee@UbunTwo:/var/node/kiwi$ sudo kiwi install ejs
   install : ejs
   version : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL /ejs/resolve was not found on this server.</p> <hr> <address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at kiwijs.com Port 80</address> </body></html>
    create : /home/bingomanatee/.kiwi/current/seeds/ejs/<!DOCTYPE
     fetch : <!DOCTYPE.seed
    unpack : /home/bingomanatee/.kiwi/current/seeds/ejs/<!DOCTYPE/ejs.seed

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
    remove : /home/bingomanatee/.kiwi/current/seeds/ejs/<!DOCTYPE
Error: failed to unpack. Seed is invalid or corrupt.
```

I may be working on a wrong assumption that kiwi downloads source as well as installs it - should I be cloning repositories before I use kiwi to install them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly from kiwi's GitHub Readme:

> NOTE: kiwi is no longer supported, please use npm. This repository will remain for educational purposes only

So you should take a look at [npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm), which as far as my experience with it goes, just works.

`ejs` is available via npm, as simple `npm install ejs` should do the job.

But make sure to install Node.js under `~` else you'll have to to use `sudo` which **is not** recommended at all, read the npm readme for further information.